# How to transform a dataframe in an ordered matrix?

Tags: r

Please, input the following code:

```
A <- matrix(11, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
A[,2] <- seq(119, 122, 1)
A[,3] <- seq(45, 42)
B <- matrix(39, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
B[,2] <- seq(119, 122, 1)
B[,3] <- seq(35, 32)
C <- matrix(67, nrow = 4, ncol = 3)
C[,2] <- seq(119, 122, 1)
C[,3] <- seq(27, 24)

D <- rbind(A, B, C)
```

You will get `D` which is a 12 x 3 matrix; I would like to know the most efficient way to obtain `Mat` starting from `D`.

```
> Mat
    11 39 67
119 45 35 27
120 44 34 26
121 43 33 25
122 42 32 24
```

In fact, `Mat` is the last column of `D` indexed by the first and the second column of `D`; e.g. consider `Mat[1,1]` which is equal to 45: it comes from the only row of `D` which is identified by 11 and 119.

How may I obatin it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(D[,3]~D[,2]+D[,1])
      D[, 1]
D[, 2] 11 39 67
   119 45 35 27
   120 44 34 26
   121 43 33 25
   122 42 32 24
```

Answer (score 2):

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(data.frame(D), X2 ~ X1)
```